# I created a "Back" button in Userform2 to display Userform1 but I get the error: Run Time Error 400 Form already displayed cannot modally

Tags: excel, vba

*Workbook code:*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

*Userform1 "Next" button Code:*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm2.Show
Unload UserForm1
Exit Sub
```

*Userform2 "Back" button Code*:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
UserForm2.Hide
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: On a second thought, move the unload Userform1 above the Userform2.Show as displaying a new userform will pause the unload code form running. Alternatively add vbmodeless after Userform2.show to avoid this issue.

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off with one form with a multipage on it.

Comment: hi Daghan I tried that but I still get the same error-i mean "unloading" vs hiding

Comment: OMG Daghan your second suggestion worked!!!! you are awesome!! yes i just switched the order now works as planned!! Thank you!!

Comment: You also may try to move that code to a module and call as a sub

Comment: I'm glad it worked, please mark the question as Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the unload Userform1 above the Userform2.Show as displaying a new userform will pause the unload code form running. Alternatively add vbmodeless after Userform2.show to avoid this issue.